# ZF2 - How to create a URI object for urls' with special characters

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In zendFramework 2, when I am trying to create a `\Zend\Uri\Uri` object for a url string which has a protocol (i.e. http/https) and special characters in the host name, `validateHost()` is not validating the host and hence exception is thrown.

But when I try to create a `Uri` object for a url string which contains special characters in the host name but without protocol, it works as expected.

In this case how should I create my Uri object?

For me the the use case is, my url string can contain url inclusive of protocol or exclusive of protocol and special characters in the host name.

E.g URI for which `Uri` object is not being created is `http://www.fitnessø.dk`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you also share an example url with that special characters?

Comment: @edigu E.g. url is `http://www.fitnessø.dk`. I just debugged more and identified that this issue is with DK domain. When I checked ZF2 `HostName` validator, I noticed that `ø` character is not registered in `$validIdns['DK']`. So is this a bug with the validator? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It's weird. I think this may be a bug. `.dk` domains allow characters like `äåæéöøü`, however Zend allows only `äéöü`. This may be due to the fact that not all web browsers support all special characters. More info about special characters in .dk domain you can find in [https://www.dk-hostmaster.dk/sites/default/files/Characters%20allowed%20in.pdf](https://www.dk-hostmaster.dk/sites/default/files/Characters%20allowed%20in.pdf) or [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dk)

Comment: @SzymonM Thanks for the information, You are correct, it was a bug indeed, I have already created a PR (https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/pull/150/commits/5520a29df26431fb611dd5df04f70b1bcfd7df9b) for the same on github.